# 3d bounding Box border xna

Tags: 3d, xna, collision, bounding-box

So, I'm trying to develop a 3d table tennis game, and I'm having problems when it comes to colliding the ball with the table. I have a bounding sphere for the ball and bounding box for the table, but the intersection isn't that accurate, and I'm guessing that the bounding box is incorrect since colliding the ball with the racket is good.

I'm trying to display the bounding box so that it would be easier to see where the error is, but I cant seem to implement the tutorials I've found with my code, or just don't know how. And, I'm I right in creating an AABB since my table isn't moving? If anyone could help, it would be greatly appreciated, or if anyone could suggest a better way to collide a ball with a box (if there is) thanks. I've pasted my bounding box detection, and the collision between the sphere and box. If more code is needed I'll post it. Thanks

```
private bool Ball_Table(Model model1, Matrix world1)
{       
    for (int meshIndex1 = 0; meshIndex1 < model1.Meshes.Count; meshIndex1++)
    {
        BoundingSphere sphere1 = model1.Meshes[meshIndex1].BoundingSphere;
        sphere1 = sphere1.Transform(world1);

        if(table_box.Intersects(sphere1))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

.

```
protected BoundingBox UpdateBoundingBox(Model model, Matrix worldTransform)
{
    // Initialize minimum and maximum corners of the bounding box to max and min values
    Vector3 min = new Vector3(float.MaxValue, float.MaxValue, float.MaxValue);
    Vector3 max = new Vector3(float.MinValue, float.MinValue, float.MinValue);

    // For each mesh of the model
    foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
    {
        foreach (ModelMeshPart meshPart in mesh.MeshParts)
        {
            // Vertex buffer parameters
            int vertexStride = meshPart.VertexBuffer.VertexDeclaration.VertexStride;
            int vertexBufferSize = meshPart.NumVertices * vertexStride;

            // Get vertex data as float
            float[] vertexData = new float[vertexBufferSize / sizeof(float)];
            meshPart.VertexBuffer.GetData<float>(vertexData);

            // Iterate through vertices (possibly) growing bounding box, all calculations are done in world space
            for (int i = 0; i < vertexBufferSize / sizeof(float); i += vertexStride / sizeof(float))
            {
                Vector3 transformedPosition = Vector3.Transform(new Vector3(vertexData[i], vertexData[i + 1], vertexData[i + 2]), worldTransform);

                min = Vector3.Min(min, transformedPosition);
                max = Vector3.Max(max, transformedPosition);
            }
        }
    }

    // Create and return bounding box
    table_box = new BoundingBox(min, max);
    return table_box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overcomplicating things. Here's my idea:

```
class Ball
{
    public Vector3 Position;
    public float Radius;

    // ...
}

class Table
{
    public Vector3 Position;
    public SizeF Size;

    // ...

    public bool CheckForCollision(Ball ball)
    {
        Vector3 upperLeftCorner = new Vector3(
                this.Position.X - this.Size.Width,
                this.Position.Y,
                this.Position.Z - this.Size.Heigth),
            lowerRightCorner = new Vector3(
                this.Position.X + this.Size.Width,
                this.Position.Y,
                this.Position.Z + this.Size.Height);

        if(ball.Position.X < upperLeftCorner.X ||
            ball.Position.X > lowerRightCorner.X)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if(ball.Position.Z < upperLeftCorner.Z ||
            ball.Position.Z > lowerRightCorner.Z)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if(ball.Position.Y - ball.Radius > this.Position.Y)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

It's been a while since I last used XNA so I might have messed up something with
coordinates, but this is what I meant to do:

```
  origin
    +---->  X, Width
    |
    |  upperLeftCorner
    |     +----------------+
    v     |                |
          |                |
    y,    |                |
  height  |                |
          |                |
          |        +       |
          | table.position |
          |                |
          |                |
          |                |
          |                |
          +----------------+
                       lowerRightCorner
```

Comment: Hey, I found out the prob, my bounding box function was giving me the wrong answers. Ye i get what your saying, in fact I created a simple bounding box from the upperleftcorner to the lowerrightcorner and removed that function and simply checked if the ball collides with it. Thanks for answering :)